# How to add a code before and after "the_content()" in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want my output to be like this -

```
echo 'codeBefore';
the_content();
echo 'codeAfter';
```

Problem is, one of the plugin i use inserts its code before and after the content & output i get is something like this.

```
  echo 'codeBefore';
  <plugin code>
  the_content();
  <plugin code>
  echo 'codeAfter';
```

How to get my code displayed in front before any other plugin codes ?

Answer (score 1):

User below Code

```
 function slideshow_fun( $content ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            $custom_content = '[plugin_shortcode]';
            $custom_content .= $content;
            return $custom_content;
        } else {
            return $content;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'slideshow_fun' );
```

[More detail and Credit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39918/wordpress-hooks-filters-insert-before-content-or-after-title#answer-39920)